# How to use for loops with a boolean array to simulate coin flip?

Tags: java, arrays

Sorry I am really new to Java and having a very difficult time with this question. I am supposed to simulate a coin flip 100 times using a method called `flipIt()` and store the result into a boolean array. However, my array just keeps printing [false, false, false, ...] 100 times. I'm not sure how to go about this, I've experimented with so many variations.

```java
public class CoinFlip {
    public static boolean[] flipResults = new boolean[100];

    public static void flipIt() {
        for (int i = 0; i < flipResults.length; i++) {
            double face = Math.random();
            if (face > .5) {
                flipResults[i] = true;
            } else {
                flipResults[i] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code seems to be fine. Can you share how you are calling this code and how you are printing the values?

Comment: *"my array just keeps printing [false, false, false, ...] 100 times"* --- Then you forgot to call the `flipIt()` *before* printing the array.

Comment: *FYI:* For a truly uniform distribution, the condition should be `(face >= .5)`

Comment: The code is working fine. It displayed both true and false when I ran it. I think you should have a look at what @Andreas mentioned.

Comment: static Boolean[] flipResults = new Boolean[100];  --> do you know see "null,null,null,..."? If yes, @Andreas gave you the answer. You are not calling flipIt()

Comment: May you be confused by the fact that static variables are loaded(and the array initialized) at the class call? Be aware that static methods are not executed: just loaded

Comment: @aran You wouldn't see null as boolean is a primitive type and defaults to false, even in an array.

Comment: @Idle_Mind, I declared the array as Boolean, not boolean. Check the comment again.The array is filled with nulls, as it should be. Boolean is not a primitive.

Comment: @aran Gotcha...you're proposing the author change from `boolean` to `Boolean` and then if they are all null references they'll know they didn't call `flipIt()`.  That's a very SUBTLE difference that wasn't obvious from your original comment.  Perhaps explicitly say that next time so people like me don't miss that point?  =)

Comment: The reason was to avoid confussion with the default behaviour of the boolean primitive. I don't know wether was helpful, but I least tried to  = ). Maybe I need to include a : "Change the array this way..." . Yep, I could agree there...

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you haven't called the function flipIt() , In java when you initialize a boolean array , it will automaticaly have all its values equal to false , once you call the function (say in main) , this should work